# Unable to clear user ID for firebase analytics iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to clear the user id of the current user after a user logs out of my app. In my log out sequence I call the following:

```
Analytics.setUserID(nil)
```

In the documentation of this method it says:

> The user ID to ascribe to the user of this app on this device, which must be non-empty and no more than 256 characters long. **Setting userID to nil removes the user ID.**

So as far as I can tell I'm clearing it correctly.

However.

When I am in debugView on firebase console, I see no indication that the user id has been cleared and when I look at subsequent events after clearing the user id, I can see under user properties, the old user id of the logged out user. I would expect this field to be empty here.

Not sure if this is a bug on debug view of the firebase console or if I'm doing something wrong?

It should be noted that when I try to set the user id as such below, I can see the user id being set in debug view and events having that id under user properties:

```
Analytics.setUserID("1234")
```